# Best way to create Image from palette Color array + indice byte array?

Tags: java, image, indices, palette

I'm developing a Java component for displaying some videos and for each frame of the video, my decoder gives me a Color[256] palette + a width*height bytes pixel indices array. Here's how I create my `BufferedImage` right now:

```
byte[] iArray = new byte[width * height * 3];
int j = 0;
for (byte i : this.lastFrameData) {
    iArray[j] = (byte) this.currentPalette[i & 0xFF].getRed();
    iArray[j + 1] = (byte) this.currentPalette[i & 0xFF].getGreen();
    iArray[j + 2] = (byte) this.currentPalette[i & 0xFF].getBlue();
    j += 3;
}
DataBufferByte dbb = new DataBufferByte(iArray, iArray.length);
ColorModel cm = new ComponentColorModel(ColorSpace.getInstance(ColorSpace.CS_sRGB), new int[] { 8, 8, 8 }, false, false, Transparency.OPAQUE, DataBuffer.TYPE_BYTE);
return new BufferedImage(cm, Raster.createInterleavedRaster(dbb, width, height, width * 3, 3, new int[] { 0, 1, 2 }, null), false, null);
```

This works but it looks ugly and I'm sure there is a better way. So what would the fastest way to create the `BufferedImage` be then?

/Edit: I've tried using the setRGB method directly on my BufferedImage but it resulted in worse performance than the above.

Thanks

Comment: This seems a pretty good approach. Is there a specific concern that you have?

Comment: I was concerned with performance mainly but it seems you are correct in that this is the fastest approach

Answer (score 0):

I would do this:

```
 int[] imagePixels = new int[width * height]

 int j = 0;
 for (byte i : this.lastFrameData) {
    byte r = (byte) this.currentPalette[i & 0xFF].getRed();
    byte g = (byte) this.currentPalette[i & 0xFF].getGreen();
    byte b = (byte) this.currentPalette[i & 0xFF].getBlue();
    imagePixels[j] = 0xFF000000 | (r<<16) | (g<<8) | b;
    j++;
 }

 BufferedImage result = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
 result.setRGB(0, 0, width, height, imagePixels , 0, width);
 return result;
```

Maybe it is faster don't test it yet.

Comment: I've compared my solution and then yours and here are the results:

2039 frames decoded in 16sec
2039 frames decoded in 22sec

it seems setRBG is slower than using a colorModel like above. thx though :)